# Offset background image and position it centrally

Tags: css, css-transitions

I would normally centre a background image using `background-size: cover`.

```
.centered image {
    background: transparent url(my-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However, in this instance I need offset the background image from the top so that it is 100px lower.

The reason being that I'm using negative top margin on the parent div but I want the background to stay where it was.

As you will see from the snippet below, the div  (red) is pulled up, then the background image is pushed back down again.

```css
.section1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lime;
}

.section2 {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: -100px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url("https://thumb.ibb.co/f1inv8/Adobe_Stock_96159207_Preview.jpg");
  background-position: center 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
</div>
<div class="section2">
</div>
```

However, if I use the background-position in this way, I can't then centre the image properly on the y-axis. It seems to default to top.

What I really want to do is align the background frame, then centre the background centrally inside that.

Anyone got any ideas as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: i don't understand why you think that the margin affects the background.

Comment: Well, if you look at the snippet, you'll see that the red (background colour) stays up with the DIV, even though I've set the background position to 100px - in other words the background color and the background image are at 2 different levels.

Comment: the background is not separate from the element that is applied to, so when you move the background down by some amount it won't go outside the element. `it's a background not an element` you might wanna use `<img>` instead.

Comment: Image is not practical in this instance - I want the image to fill the space not dictate it. All I want to do is be able  to position my image centrally while offsetting it in relation to the div top.

Comment: `<Img>` is your best bet right now, because what you're trying do is impossible with the background

Comment: Check out my answer, i think it's working the way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you a much more clear example of what's happening.

We gonna have an `div` and we gonna mimic the background with an `img` tag inside that div.

That div is basically an element with overflow:hidden for the background,  what i mean is that normally when you set overflow:hidden on an element, if it's content is larger than it, it just hide what's outside.

the background however is not but it has that overflow property to be hidden for it, so if the background is larger it just gets cut of, until you resize it with background-size:100% 100%; to make it fit on both axis.

**Example**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* to mimic the img being cut of, if it's larger*/
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  /* to have a visual understanding*/
}

.test {
  background: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/f1inv8/Adobe_Stock_96159207_Preview.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/f1inv8/Adobe_Stock_96159207_Preview.jpg" class="background">
</div>

<div class="test"></div>
```

I hope you now understands what's happening.

---

So to achieve what you want is pretty  simple using an `<img>`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lime;
}

.section2 {
  height: 200px;
  margin: -100px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.section2>img {
  margin-top: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
</div>
<div class="section2">
  <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/f1inv8/Adobe_Stock_96159207_Preview.jpg">
</div>
```

isn't this is what you're looking for, pushing the div upward yet the background stays where it was ?
It can be perfected using flex, but i'll that to you.

Comment: It looks like it could be correct - I'll check it out. Learn something new every day - I didn't know about object fit.

Comment: `Object-fit` is specifically for `<img>` And ` <video>`  [MDN Object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate background vertical position subtracting 50px (half of 100px) from center (50%)

```css
.section1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lime;
}

.section2 {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: -100px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url("https://thumb.ibb.co/f1inv8/Adobe_Stock_96159207_Preview.jpg");
  background-position: center calc(50% - 50px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
</div>
<div class="section2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts - unfortunately this doesn't work. The offset should always be 100px (which it is not with your solution), and the image should be centered inside the offset background.

Comment: No. Negative margin pulls the Div up background-position pushes it back down. In order to return to the starting point it must always equal the negative margin. The position must always be 100px.